# Declaring variables inside loop in apex

Tags: apex, loop

In apex declaring variable inside the loop will affect the performance ? What is the exact difference between declaring variables inside loop and outside loop in apex ?

Can I have any reference from salesforce site ?

**Inside loop :**

```
for (sobject sobj : sobjs) {
       String name = (String)sobj.get('name');
.............
}
```

**Outside loop :**

```
String name;
for (sobject sobj : sobjs) {
        name = (String)sobj.get('name');
...................
}
```

Comment: I would assume, impact should be similar to what we have in java. However, i dont have any SFDC documentation to point at. This one points out from Java perspective --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop

Comment: One more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The differences:

1. Scope: if you define name outside the loop, the name viable's scope will be accessible outside the loop. This is the major difference.
2. Heap size: defining name inside the loop will create n instances of variables (n is the length of your array), each of them is different. Garbage collection will collect them up but no one knows when.
3. Performance perspective, the impact is minimal.

Comment: Do we have any salesforce link about this ?

Comment: @SANN3 Don't think so. If you really want to know the answer, a proper performance test can help. However, I don't think it is even worthwhile to do it.

Comment: It really depends on how you wish to use your variable. As stated above, performance impact is minimal, all you need to know is the scope of your variable use accordingly.

Comment: On 2), in both forms of the code there will be no difference in heap usage as the characters of the string are located on the heap and the likely implementation is that just the reference (pointer) to the string referenced by `sobj` is assigned. The `name` variable will be located on the stack in both cases: just enough space for a single reference (pointer) is needed, 4 or 8 bytes. See e.g. [What and where are the stack and heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: @KeithC Thank you for pointing out. But the stack memory will be different. Right?

Comment: @LanceShi More likely the same than different. In both cases the compiler just has to recognise that there is a `name` variable that it needs to reserve space for. On entering a method/function the stack pointer is advanced to provide enough space for all the local variables (including `name` ) and on exiting the stack pointer is set back to its original value. No stack pointer adjustment happens within the direct statements in the method/function.

Comment: @KeithC I see. Thanks. I am a bit surprised to see the inside solution is actually a little faster in Java situation.